# Why spin Hall effect (SHE) is mathematicaly represented by the antisymmetric part of conductivity tensor?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect

The spin current $\mathbf{J^\gamma}$ due to the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is mathematically given by
$$
\mathbf{J^\gamma = \sigma^\gamma E}
$$
here $\gamma$ shows spin-component, and $\mathbf{\sigma^\gamma}$ represent spin conductivity tensor. I read in an article that SHE $\mathbf{\Omega^\gamma}$ is mathematically represented by the anti-symmetric part of the conductivity tensor $\sigma^\gamma$ i.e.
$$
\mathbf{\Omega^\gamma} = \frac{\sigma^\gamma-(\sigma^{\gamma})^T}{2} 
$$
The publication is:

> [Origin of the Magnetic Spin Hall Effect: Spin Current Vorticity in the Fermi Sea](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13375)
> by Alexander Mook, Robin R. Neumann, Annika Johansson, Jürgen Henk, Ingrid Mertig

The exact words (on the first page, 2nd paragraph) are

> While the anomalous Hall effect (AHE) in a magnet
> produces a transverse charge current density upon applying an
> electric field $E$, the SHE in a nonmagnet produces a transverse
> spin current density $\langle J^\gamma \rangle = \sigma^\gamma E$, $\gamma$ indicates the
> transported spin component). **Mathematically, the SHE is
> quantified by the antisymmetric part of the spin conductivity
> tensor $\sigma^\gamma$ . For example, the $\sigma_{xy}^z$ element comprises z-polarized
> spin currents in the x-direction as a response to an electric field
> in the y-direction**

Why SHE has to be the anti-symmetric part and not the full $\sigma^\gamma$ tensor?

Answer (score 2):

The Hall effect, whether Spin, anomalous, or regular variety, is a transverse current due to a longitudinal electromotive force. That is, a current in $y$ due to a voltage across $x$. This component is represented by the off-diagonal elements of the conductivity tensor.  Moreover, knowing how, for example, the SHE transforms with inversion, we can specify that it will be antisymmetric (only the off-diagonal elements can possibly be antisymmetric). The diagonal elements of the tensor refer to a current in $x$ due to a voltage in $x$, and similarly $y$ current for $y$ voltage. This is an important part of the tensor, it’s just not a Hall effect. Rather, the diagonal represents regular conductivity.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So, Hall effects are connected with $\sigma_{ij}$ with $i\ne j$ components of conductivity tensor. According to the article that I've mentioned, for a 2D system, the SHE conductivity tensor is
$$
\Omega^\gamma = \frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&(\sigma_{xy}^\gamma - \sigma_{yx}^\gamma)\\
-(\sigma_{xy}^\gamma - \sigma_{yx}^\gamma)&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
my confusion is, why SHE is $\sigma_{xy}^\gamma - \sigma_{yx}^\gamma$ and not only $\sigma_{xy}^\gamma$?